# Disable one or many selected Items in React Bootstrap Async Typeahead

Tags: asynchronous, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using react-bootstrap-typeahead for adding items in to a list.
I want to disable remove button of the added items according to a condition.

https://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`renderToken`](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Rendering.md#rendertokenoption-objectstring-props-object-index-number) prop to customize how the tokens are rendered.

The tokens themselves accept a `disabled` prop. If `true`, the token will be read-only **and** have a disabled appearance.

Alternatively, omitting the `onRemove` prop on the token will make it read-only without the disabled appearance.

Here's a basic example of how to specify each of the methods described above:

```jsx
<Typeahead
  ...
  multiple
  renderToken={(option, props, idx) => (
    <Token
      disabled={idx === 0}
      onRemove={idx === 1 ? undefined : props.onRemove}>
      {option.label}
    </Token>
  )}
/>
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-typeahead-token-customization-495-54gtg

**Note:** In both the disabled and read-only cases, users **will not be able to remove** the selections once added, so be careful about the user experience. The `disabled` state is generally best used when the entire typeahead is disabled. In that case, the `disabled` state is automatically passed down to the token components. Read-only selections are good when you want to pre-select required options, for example.

Comment: Hi ericgio, Thank you very much for the explanation and the example. It was a really helpful explanation. Big thank..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to disable it:

```
<Joyride
   styles={
             {
                buttonClose: {
                   display: 'none',
                },
             }
   }
```